# Can someone solve level 12 of this logic game

Tags: アルゴリズム

I run into this game and manage to solve level one to eleven but not able to solve level twelve, I think it is recursive algorithm, sorry if this is not question for this site :)
Here is the link
http://ftzzle.42.us.org/index.html

※４２Tokyoの公式サイトの練習問題です。
どうしても１２が解けないので誰か力を貸してください。

Comment: 「1マス前進」と「反時計回りに90°回転」を F2 に割り当てます。そして F3 には 「1マス前進」+ F2 を割り当てます。そして、F4 には… とすればよろしいかと。

Comment: できないようなのですが、F1、F5も教えてください。

Comment: ご自身がどのようなことを試されたのかが質問文にあると回答しやすいです。スクリーンショットを添付したりもできます。「編集」から自由に追記できますのでお試しください。　／　このサイトは日本語で運営されておりますので、英語はあってもなくてもOKです :)

Comment: ご丁寧にありがとうございます。F2の二マス目にF？をなにか入れないと次に飛ばないという先入観がありました。最初F1には矢印などをいれていましたがすべてF？になるんですね。頂いたヒントを元にクリアすることができました。お礼申し上げます。

Comment: @user37766 お見事！

Comment: @user37766 さん> もし問題が解決されたのであれば、解決した方法を回答として投稿し、質問を解決済みにしていただけませんか？

Answer (score 1):

実際の解答例です。

下記の灰色部分にマウスオーバーするとレベル12の解答が表示されます。
挑戦中の方はご注意ください。

> [image: 解答例]